# Variance of beta distribution (fastest way)

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, beta-distribution

Suppose a Random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Beta}(a,b)$

Find the $\mathrm{Var}( \frac{X}{1-X} ) $

My initial approach is to calculate  $\mathrm{E}( \frac{X}{1-X} ) $ and  $\mathrm{E}( [\frac{X}{1-X}]^2 ) $

And then find it :

$\mathrm{Var}( \frac{X}{1-X} )  =  \mathrm{E}[ (\frac{X}{1-X})^2 ]  - \mathrm{E}[(\frac{X}{1-X})]^2  $

Where   $\mathrm{E}( \frac{X}{1-X} )  = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{X}{1-X} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x=\ldots $

My question first of all is if this approach is correct.

Also,

**Is there a quicker way to calculate the** $\mathrm{Var}( \frac{X}{1-X} ) $?

Or could you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: Quicker in what sense? Monte Carlo simulation would take about a minute, including time needed to write the code.

Comment: Sorry , I meant quicker without the use of codes. With another approach like formula etc

Comment: X/(1-X) follows a well-know distribution, Then you can write its variance very first.

Comment: I did the transformation $Y= \frac{X}{1-X}$ but  I wasn't sure if I know the new distribution of Y

Comment: Y follows a well-know distribution, you can find it from Wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution gives the answer, but does not reveal whether there is a quicker way to obtain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks correct--but there are some ways to do the integration without much work.

**Let's begin by listing the simplest and most obvious facts about Beta distributions.**

1. It is apparent from almost any characterization of these distributions that when a random variable $X$ has a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution, then $Y=1-X$ has a Beta$(b,a)$ distribution.
2. The unnormalized density function $f_{a,b}$ of a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution is a multiple of $x^{a};$ that is, it can be expressed as $$f_{a,b}(x) = x^{a} g_{b}(x).$$
3. The normalizing constant of a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution is

$$B(a,b) = \int f_{a,b}(y)\mathrm{d}y = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

where the gamma function has the property that for any $z$ that is not zero or a negative integer,

$$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z).$$

(If you didn't know this you could still compute the variance as shown below, but you wouldn't obtain a simplified formula for it.)

**These suffice, along with the variance formula**

$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$$

and the (easily proven) fact that $\operatorname{Var}(X+\lambda) = \operatorname{Var}(X)$ for any constant $\lambda,$ to obtain an answer simply.  Here's how it goes:

First, algebra gives

$$Z=\frac{X}{1-X} = \frac{1}{1-X} -1 = \frac{1}{Y}-1$$

where $Y=1-X$ has a Beta$(b,a)$ distribution by $(1).$  Thus, we obtain moments of $Y$ from $(2),$ *without any calculation,* as

$$\eqalign{
\mu_k(Y) 
&= \frac{1}{B(b,a)}\int y^k f_{b,a}(y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{B(b,a)}\int y^k y^{b} g_{a}(y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{B(b,a)}\int y^{b+k} g_{a}(y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{B(b,a)}\int f_{b+k,a}(y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{B(b+k,a)}{B(b,a)}.
}$$

> **Consequently the variance is** $$\eqalign{
> \operatorname{Var}(Z) &=\operatorname{Var}(Y^{-1}-1)= \operatorname{Var}(Y^{-1}) = E\left((Y^{-1})^2\right) - E\left(Y^{-1}\right)^2 \\
> &= \mu_{-2}(Y)-(\mu_{-1}(Y))^2 \\
> &= \frac{B(b-2,a)}{B(b,a)} -\left(\frac{B(b-1,a)}{B(b,a)}\right)^2.
> }
> $$

**This simplifies to**

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\right)=\frac{B(b-2,a)}{B(b,a)} -\left(\frac{B(b-1,a)}{B(b,a)}\right)^2 = \frac{a(a+b-1)}{(b-2)(b-1)^2}.$$

The only algebra needed to achieve the last step--and therefore the only calculation in the entire derivation--comes from the relation $(3)$ and the assumption that everything is well-defined, which it will be when $b-2\gt 0$ (for otherwise the expectation of $Y^{-2}$ diverges).